# How much detail is enough to start a campaign?

Tags: dnd-5e, campaign-development, new-gm

As a new DM and new to the whole pen and paper genre, I am wondering how much detailed should my world be at the beginning of a campaign.

For example, if a player wants to create a cleric, I should probably have already picked what gods exist in my world for them to choose from.

Also, considering that the PCs are supposed to have lived in the world, shouldn't they also know of any kingdoms etc. that exist in the world? Wouldn't that though defeat the whole concept of organically creating the world along the campaign as PCs adventure through it? And wouldn't it be too tiresome to detail and keep notes from the very start of all the laws and history a world has in order not to lose coherence in case a PC asks a question that could connect to the whole universe?

Comment: You're asking a whole bunch of related questions here, and several of those questions are too subjective to have one right answer, and some of them have been asked before, and some of them would take a small book to explain. This question is going to be put on hold until you can narrow it down a bit more.

Comment: [chat] may be a place where we can help you scope this question and figure out how to get some good wisdom.

Comment: What books and other resources do have available to you now?  If you have one of the beginner modules, the answer will be different than if you have only the on line available rules, which will be different if you have some or all of the core books: Players Handbook, Monster Manual, Dungeon Master's Guide.

Comment: I have all three core books, with only PHB whole read and DMG half way through.